# Pine Script - not trade until after specific number of bars since last dinvestment

Tags: pine-script

I want to institute a delay in bars or time before allowing buy condition to trigger. I tried the below code but when added 'wait' to buycondition it never trades.  i believe this is because it never gets off barsfromclose because their was never a starting 'buy' leading to a sell and therefore its sits at a zero position from the start and so never trades.

```
barsfromclose = ta.barssince(strategy.position_size[1] > 0)
barstowait = input.int(title = "Bars to Wait", defval = 3)
wait = barsfromclose > barstowait
```

Comment: Do you want your buy condition to stay `true` during that wait time?

Comment: no. if during the intervening period the signal no longer remains valid then so be it.  the purpose is to combine with take profit and force a pause before going back in

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this by using solution from FAQ:

https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-implement-a-time-delay-between-orders-1

Comment: Thanks you SL! Works perfectly